# Make an Image In Perspective

Tags: java, android

As the title says I wonder how I can make my images to perspective view. Here's an image showing how they manage to do this in photoshop:

http://netlumination.com/blog/creating-perspective-and-a-mirror-image-in-photoshop

Is it possible to do something like this in android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Have a look at this page http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/12/android-reflections-with-bitmaps.html.
You can then apply an AffineTransform (at least in AWT, but Android should have something similar, too) using a [matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to distort/skew the image.

**Edit:** see http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html for an implementation of a PerspectiveFilter.

Note that you could probably also use openGL to achieve a similar effect. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

Comment: It seems like matrix is the way to go, but I can't figure out how I should use it. I tried the following:


Matrix srcmatrix = new Matrix();
srcmatrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
srcmatrix.setSkew(4, 4);
mImageView.setImageMatrix(srcmatrix);


mImageView is the View Which contains my bitmap image.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for me, for values of rotation between 0 and 60:

```
    Matrix imageMatrix = new Matrix();
    float[] srcPoints = {
        0, 0,
        0, 200,
        200, 200,
        200, 0};

    float[] destPoints = {
        rotation, rotation/2f,
        rotation, 200 - rotation/2f,
        200 - rotation, 200,
        200 - rotation, 0};
    imageMatrix.setPolyToPoly(srcPoints, 0, destPoints, 0, 4);
```